# codewars test suite expected output mismatch

Tags: javascript, types

I'm doing some practice on codewars and I don't understand what is causing my program to fail the test suite. The code is supposed to find the min value in an array or the index of the min value based on the second parameter passed in. Here is my code followed by two test functions:

```
//my code
function min(arr, toReturn) {
  var min = arr[0];
  var index = 0;
  for(var i in arr){
    if(arr[i] < min){
      min = arr[i];
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return toReturn === "value" ? min : index;
}

// example function usage
Test.assertEquals(min([1,2,3,4,5], 'value'), 1)
Test.assertEquals(min([1,2,3,4,5], 'index'), 0)
```

My function passes the two tests above. I run the full test suite and I get an error "Expected: 5, instead got: 5" I'm not sure why this is because I set my min variable from arr for the value and index should just be a number, so idk how it could be a type mismatch. Does anyone have any ideas about what is happening here?

Comment: did you tried `index = parseInt(i)` in your `for loop`?

Comment: @SinaSadrzadeh yea that worked, but why? I initialize index as a number and I though i in the for loop would be a number as well. Is that not the case? I'm trying to better understand the loose type system in Javascript coming from a Java background.

Comment: `for each` in javascript is a little tricky. if you declare a variable as index (such as `i` in your case ), it will be treated as `string`. you can write the same scenario with a simple `for loop` without any prob.

Comment: I think your Q is eligible for an up vote, because its a good point about javascript `for each`